# Postgres SELECT or INSERT in CTE?

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression

I'm using Postgres 12.2.

I try to fill a kind of event table where I have one column which needs to get the id of something.

In the example I created, the events are stored in the `purchases` table while the id needs to be the id of the company, taken from the `companies` table. As there is no fixed set of companies, the companies table needs to "grow as I go" ;).

So the setup is:

```
CREATE TABLE 
    companies 
    ( 
        company_id  SERIAL NOT NULL, 
        NAME        CHARACTER VARYING(256) NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (company_id), 
        CONSTRAINT companies_unique_name UNIQUE (NAME) 
    )
;
CREATE TABLE 
    purchases
    ( 
        purchase_id    SERIAL NOT NULL, 
        purchase_date  DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE NOT NULL, 
        amount         INTEGER NOT NULL,
        company_id     INTEGER NOT NULL, 
        PRIMARY KEY (purchase_id) 
    )
;
```

So when I now want to insert the event "Purchased 5 items from 'company1'", I need to get the id of "company1" by either looking it up in the `companies` table or by creating a new entry for "company1" in `companies`.

I can do it like this:

```
WITH EXISTING_COMPANY AS (
        SELECT company_id FROM companies WHERE name = 'company1'
)
   , NEW_COMPANY AS (
        INSERT INTO companies (name) VALUES ('company1')
        ON CONFLICT(name) DO NOTHING
        RETURNING company_id
)
   , GET_COMPANY_ID AS (
        SELECT COALESCE(
            (SELECT company_id FROM EXISTING_COMPANY),
            (SELECT company_id FROM NEW_COMPANY)
   ) AS company_id
)
INSERT INTO purchases(amount, company_id)
VALUES (5, (select company_id from GET_COMPANY_ID))
;
```

The CTE `EXISTING_COMPANY` will give me the id of an existing "company1" or `null`.

The CTE `NEW_COMPANY` will give me the id of a newly created company "company1" or `null`

The CTE `GET_COMPANY_ID` finally will, by using `coalesce`, try to get an existing id and, if that fails, a new id.

While this works it has the disadvantages that I need to give the company name twice and that I need new CTEs for each company as I do not know how to pass the company name to my CTEs.

- Is there a way how to pass the company name to my CTEs?
- Are there other ways to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3):

You can provide the new name with a `values()` clause in another CTE. You also don't really need the `existing_company` CTE as that can also be done inside the `get_company` cte:

```
WITH input(name) as (
  values ('company1')
), new_company AS (

  INSERT INTO companies (name) 
  select i.name 
  from input i
  ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
  RETURNING company_id

), get_company_id AS (
  select company_id
  from new_company

  union all

  select company_id
  from companies
  where name in (select name from input)
    and not exists (select * from new_company)
)
INSERT INTO purchases(amount, company_id)
select 5, company_id 
from get_company_id
;
```

This can also be extended to handle multiple companies and amounts:

```
WITH input(amount, name) as (
  values 
     (5, 'company1'), 
     (6, 'company2')
), new_company AS (
  INSERT INTO companies (name) 
  select name 
  from input
  ON CONFLICT (name) DO NOTHING
  RETURNING company_id, name
), get_company_id AS (

  select company_id, name
  from new_company
  union all

  select c.company_id, c.name
  from companies c
  where c.name in (select i.name from input i)
  and not exists (select * 
                  from new_company nc
                  where nc.company_id = c.company_id)
)
INSERT INTO purchases(amount, company_id)
select i.amount, g.company_id 
from get_company_id g
  join input i on i.name = g.name
;
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong but doesn't this try an INSERT first and then a SELECT? As I expect to have more "reoccurring" companies than new ones, wouldn't it be more efficient the other way around? That's why I used `coalesce` as it doesn't evaluate the INSERT when the SELECT succeeded.

Comment: The INSERT is **always** executed, regardless whether you select from its corresponding CTE or not.

Comment: I double checked that by adding a column to the `companies` table and changing its value in the `ON CONFLICT`. You are right. Then it seems I do not understand (cite) "The COALESCE function evaluates arguments from left to right until it finds the first non-null argument. All the remaining arguments from the first non-null argument are not evaluated." found here: https://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-coalesce/

Comment: @Skeeve: actually it's because of "*Data-modifying statements in WITH are executed exactly once, and always to completion, independently of whether the primary query reads all (or indeed any) of their output*" (see https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/queries-with.html#QUERIES-WITH-MODIFYING)

Answer (score 0):

I looked into functions and I'm experimenting with this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION companyID (IN company_name VARCHAR(256))
RETURNS integer AS
'
DECLARE
        cid integer;
BEGIN
        SELECT company_id INTO cid FROM companies WHERE name = company_name;
        IF cid IS NULL THEN
                INSERT INTO companies (name) VALUES(company_name)
                ON CONFLICT(name) DO NOTHING
                RETURNING company_id INTO cid;
        END IF;
        -- In case of a concurrent insert, cid could be null
        IF cid IS NULL THEN
                SELECT company_id INTO cid FROM companies WHERE name = company_name;
        END IF;
        RETURN cid;
END;
'
LANGUAGE plpgsql
;
```

The insert then works like this:

```
INSERT INTO purchases (amount, company_id) VALUES
(10, companyID('company2')),
(11, companyID('company1')),
(42, companyID('company2'))
;
```

Are there any disadvantages in this approach?

Comment: This is not safe for concurrent inserts

Comment: Thanks. I made an attempt to resolve it by ignoring insert conflicts and retrieving the concurrently inserted id in case of such a conflict. Does that look better? Any other disadvantages?